# Dynamic lookups in Acumatica

Tags: acumatica

Is there a way to build lookups in Acumatica dynamically? Kinda like you can do with grids using a view delegate. Basically I need to be able to run some calculations over INLotSerialStatus table, which shows lot quantities. Based on those calculations I would like to display the right lots and updated quantities.

The way I've done this so far is to create a temporary table and a DAC to fill it out from somewhere (don't know exactly a good place to do this from) and use this temp table as a lookup. I see all sorts of problems with that, such as multiple user correctly updating this lookup, even if I have a user id and inventory id in this temp table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A concept identical to data view delegates is also implemented for the **PXCustomSelectorAttribute**. You should simply inherit from **PXCustomSelectorAttribute** and declare the **GetRecords()** method returning **IEnumerable**:

```
public class PXWeekSelectorAttribute : PXCustomSelectorAttribute
{
    ...
    protected IEnumerable GetRecords()
    {
        ...
        var cache = _Graph.Caches[_CacheType];
        var startDate = cache.GetValue(cache.Current, _startDateOrdinal);
        return GetRecordsByDate((DateTime?)startDate);
    }
    ...
    public static IEnumerable GetRecordsByDate(DateTime? startDate)
    {
        if (startDate == null) yield break;

        var date = (DateTime)startDate;
        var dateWeek = PX.Data.EP.PXDateTimeInfo.GetWeekNumber(date);
        var utcDate = PXTimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeToUtc(date, LocaleInfo.GetTimeZone());
        var utcDateWeek = PX.Data.EP.PXDateTimeInfo.GetWeekNumber(utcDate);
        if (dateWeek != utcDateWeek)
        {
            if (date > utcDate)
            {
                yield return new EPWeek { WeekID = utcDate.Year * 100 + utcDateWeek };
                yield return new EPWeek { WeekID = date.Year * 100 + dateWeek };
            }
            else
            {
                yield return new EPWeek { WeekID = date.Year * 100 + dateWeek };
                yield return new EPWeek { WeekID = utcDate.Year * 100 + utcDateWeek };
            }
        }
        else
            yield return new EPWeek { WeekID = date.Year * 100 + dateWeek };
    }
    ...
}
```

Comment: What is the difference between GetRecords and GetRecordsByName? Does the method name needs to match to anything, like the view delegate does to the view?

Comment: Nvm saw it. So I guess you need to have GetRecords defined. And IEnumerable can be of any DAC.

Comment: Ruslan, do you know if you can access current cache and a line, where you are doing the lookup? Kinda like you can access current graph with this._Graph

Comment: `_Graph.Caches[_CacheType].Current` should return the current line from the cache of your choice.

Comment: Thanks again Ruslan. Yuriy has an excellent example for custom lookups also: http://blog.zaletskyy.com/custom-selector-in-acumatica